# Xammp virtual host problem on Mac

Tags: virtualhost, mac

I followed this tutorial on how to set up a virtual host: http://optionexplicit.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/xampp-virtual-hosts-on-a-mac/

Now, I have to admit i'm a newbie in these kind of things and i'd just like to make that server/site visible to everyone that access that web address, for instance zendapplication.dev.

How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Get MAMP here: http://www.mamp.info/de/index.html

Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "everyone" you are talking about are other computers on your network you would have to modify the hosts file on those computers as mentioned in the tutorial you linked to, but instead of 127.0.0.1 you would put the IP address of the computer running XAMPP (ie 192.168.0.100).

Your other option is to setup a local DNS server and create your zendapplication.dev entry there.